# Nginx: Rewrite URL to hash

Tags: nginx

I have an old site which has been upgraded to an SPA frontend, so now the URLs to access certain records use the hash, so the URLs changed from like example.com/aq/12345 => example.com/#/aq/12345

This is already working fine, but I also wanted to set up a redirect so that anyone who had the old URLs would be redirected to the new URLs. I tried setting up the rewrite like this:

```
    location / {
        root /var/www/frontend;
        autoindex on;

        rewrite ^/aq/(.*)/$ /#/aq/$1/ last;
    }
```

... but when I did this, nginx simply started looking for a file named `/var/www/frontend/#/aq/[whatever]/index.html`, instead of simply redirecting to `/var/www/frontend/index.html` with the hash in the URL. What is the proper way to configure this, or is not possible to do this at all?

Comment: Instead of `last` flag, use `permanent` for 301 redirect or `redirect` for 302 redirect. `rewrite` directive is more flexible than `return` because it allows to analyze and manipulate original URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to use the HTTP 301 status code:

```
 location /aq {
        root /var/www/frontend;
        autoindex on;

        return 301 https://example.com/#$request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I suppose it means I need to one such location directive for each subpath I want to redirect right? (/aq was just one example out of many...)

Comment: Yes, it depends on how many SPAs you have there - but each SPA only needs 1 location block as each block will catch all of its corresponding `#hash`-based routes.